# str_replace not working on database return

Tags: php, mysql, string, str-replace

I'm getting stumped by what should be a really simple str_replace function.
In my database, I have a field for a minecraft server motd(message of the day). When I collect data from servers I store the data including the motd in my database.

Servers are able to color motds by adding a color code, which I have stored in the database as &sect then a number specifying the color. I'm trying to use str_replace to turn the &sectnumber into an html element with the actual color. I  came up with the following code:

```
if ($server_data['show_motd'] == 1) {
        $motd = $server_data['motd'];
        $motd = str_replace("&sect0","</span><span style=\"color:#000\">", $motd);
        $motd = str_replace("&sect1","</span><span style=\"color:#00A\">", $motd);
        $motd = str_replace("&sect2","</span><span style=\"color:#0A0\">", $motd);
        $motd = str_replace("&sect3","</span><span style=\"color:#0AA\">", $motd);
        $motd = str_replace("&sect4","</span><span style=\"color:#A00\">", $motd);
        $motd = str_replace("&sect5","</span><span style=\"color:#A0A\">", $motd);
        $motd = str_replace("&sect6","</span><span style=\"color:#FA0\">", $motd);
        $motd = str_replace("&sect7","</span><span style=\"color:#AAA\">", $motd);
        $motd = str_replace("&sect8","</span><span style=\"color:#555\">", $motd);
        $motd = str_replace("&sect9","</span><span style=\"color:#55F\">", $motd);
        $motd = str_replace("&secta","</span><span style=\"color:#5F5\">", $motd);
        $motd = str_replace("&sectb","</span><span style=\"color:#5FF\">", $motd);
        $motd = str_replace("&sectc","</span><span style=\"color:#F55\">", $motd);
        $motd = str_replace("&sectd","</span><span style=\"color:#F5F\">", $motd);
        $motd = str_replace("&secte","</span><span style=\"color:#FF5\">", $motd);
        $motd = str_replace("&sectf","</span><span style=\"color:#FFF\">", $motd);

        echo "

    <tr>
    <td class=\"serverdisplayspan\">MOTD:</td>
    <td class=\"serverdisplaylidet\"><span>$motd</span</td>
    </tr>
    ";
}
```

However, none of the str_replace functions are doing anything. The weird thing is that when I replace

```
$motd = $server_data['motd'];
```

with

```
$motd = "&sectcWelcome to &sectbSkyBlock&sectc!"
```

which is what is stored in the database, it works perfectly. Without the str_replaces, the two variables look exactly the same. I've even checked the type of each variable using gettype()
 and both of them are strings. I've also tried utf_decode() on the database result, but nothing seems to work.

Is there some difference between the database result and the string i just typed in? I can't find out what it is but there must obviously be one.

Thanks.

Comment: So the value in your database is `&sectcWelcome to &sectbSkyBlock&sectc!` ?

Comment: Yeah, the value in the database is exactly that.

Comment: And to be clear, when you use `$motd = "&sectcWelcome to &sectbSkyBlock&sectc!"` - all of the string replace functions are working?

Comment: Yeah, that string is displayed as colored text exactly how I meant it to.

Comment: When you look at the value from the database, are you viewing it in an HTML document? If so, it's probably `&amp;sectcWelcome to &amp;sectbSkyBlock&amp;sectc!`

Comment: Phil that made a ton of sense, I tried changing the string to `$motd = "&amp;sectcWelcome to &amp;sectbSkyBlock&amp;sectc!";` and then it looked exactly like the database result and would not get colored, however when i added the line `$motd = str_replace("&amp;","&", $motd);` the written string again colored and left the database result uncolored

Comment: Sorry I'm actually not viewing the database value in an HTML document. I'm viewing it in phpmyadmin which I think displays the raw database value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this (swaps out your inline styles for CSS classes)

```
$motd = preg_replace('/&(amp;)?(sect[0-9a-f])/',
    '</span><span class="$2">', $motd);
```

Quick demo here with mixed `&` and `&amp;` - http://codepad.viper-7.com/12phow

With this, you'll also want to add something like this to your stylesheet

```
.sect0 { color: #000; }
.sect1 { color: #00A; }
.sect2 { color: #0A0; }
/* etc */
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I tried it and it again worked for written version but not for the database. Do you know if theres something other than the & that is changed when written to an html document? Is there a way to see the pure code?

Comment: @mongy910 You'll need to provide an *actual* value from your database. View the source (as in right-click -> view source) of your page to get the raw HTML value

Comment: the view source of the page just says "&sectcWelcome to &sectbSkyBlock&sectc!" It doesn't seem to give the raw value

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and fixed it by using

```
mysqli_set_charset($con,'utf8');
```

right after

```
mysqli_connect
```